# Max Date & Min Date in sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

Anyone please help me

How to use SQL to find yesterday max time and today min time. I need yesterday's max time `Tine_in` and today's min time yesterday `Time_out`.

Like this:

I have a table like this:

```
|--ID--|--Time-------|--Date------|  
|--1---|08:03:00 PM|04/01/2014|  
|--1---|08:07:00 AM|04/02/2014|   
|--1---|08:11:00 PM|04/02/2014|  
|--1---|08:02:00 AM|04/03/2014|  
|--1---|08:10:00 PM|04/03/2014|  
|--1---|08:05:00 AM|04/04/2014|  
|--1---|08:10:00 PM|04/04/2014|  
|--1---|08:06:00 AM|04/05/2014|  
|--1---|08:15:00 PM|04/05/2014|  
|--1---|08:01:00 AM|04/06/2014|  
|--1---|08:08:00 PM|04/06/2014|
```

I need these results:

```
|--ID--|--Date------|--Time_in----|--Time_out--|  
|--1---|04/01/2014|08:03:00 PM|08:07:00 AM|  
|--1---|04/02/2014|08:11:00 PM|08:02:00 AM|  
|--1---|04/03/2014|08:10:00 PM|08:05:00 AM|  
|--1---|04/04/2014|08:10:00 PM|08:06:00 AM|  
|--1---|04/05/2014|08:10:00 PM|08:01:00 AM|  
|--1---|04/06/2014|08:08:00 PM|00:00:00 ----|
```

Like 04/02/2014 MAX time 04/02/2014 Time_in and 04/03/2014 MIN Time 04/02/2014 Time_Out.

Thanks..

Comment: Are your IDs really all the same?

Comment: You know, I'd find that result dataset very misleading - it ends up looking like `Time Out` is the same day, but it really belongs to the **next** day.  Why are you displaying it like this?  What happens if the resulting `Time Out` is before the `Time In`?  What should happen in the case that there's a gap (ie, say 4/5 has no entries)?  Should that last result row really have `null` (which is what the data is)? ...Oh, and what version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you are querying for this (stored proc, view, etc), but here is a generic advice:

For the purpose of your query, combine the Date and Time columns into one column (of type datetime or smalldatetime). Now find the min and max of that. You should be set!

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood the task, but you can do a self join as in:

`with t(t) as ( 
    values '2014-04-01-08.03.00'
          ,'2014-04-02-08.07.00'
          ,'2014-04-02-08.11.00'
          ,'2014-04-03-08.02.00'
) 
select max(t1.t), min(t2.t) 
from t t1 
join t t2 
    on date(t1.t) = date(t2.t) - 1 day 
group by date(t1.t)`

FWIW you will get more answers if you provide sample data as either insert statements or cte (like above).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group by` with `min` and `max`

```
select
  [Date],
  Min([Time]) As Time_In,
  Max([Time]) As Time_Out

from Table1

group by
  [Date]
```

Also note that `Time` and `Date` are reserved words in SQL server.  You should consider renaming those columns.

Answer (score 0):

For each date the latest time and the next day's earliest time:

```
WITH cte AS
 ( SELECT
      d,
      MIN(t) AS mint, 
      MAX(t) AS maxt
   FROM tab
   GROUP BY d
 )
SELECT
   t1.d,
   t1.maxt, 
   COALESCE(t2.mint, '00:00:00')
FROM cte AS t1 
LEFT JOIN cte AS t2
  ON t1.d = t2.d-1
```